# Cannot reference a property without removing the Namespace or adding Global in front

Tags: .net, vb.net, global-namespace

I got a solution with several projects and was working fine. One fine day, hundreds of errors cropped out, apparently from nowhere!

After hours trying to find out why, I noticed that any Property within a project with Namespace '`IBS_DAL`' cannot be referenced as `IBS_DAL.PropertyName`. It can either be referenced as `Global.IBS_DAL.PropertyName`  or just `PropertyName`. The error states:

> Type `IBS_DAL.PropertyName` is not defined.

Can anyone please tell me what could I have changed in my solution.

Sample Code:

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Data.Linq.Mapping
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports J2.J2Errors
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading

Imports System.Transactions
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class ImportRawData

    Dim P1 As Global.IBS_DAL.Stock = Nothing
    Dim P2 As IBS_DAL.Stock = Nothing
...
```

[image]

In project `IBS DAL`, `P1` works fine, but `P2` does not.
Outside project `IBS DAL`, both work fine.

Thanks
JP

Comment: Chances are, the word "static " has been removed from the IBS_DAL class declaration.

Comment: Can you show the definition of `PropertyName` and from where it's being referenced?

Comment: I'm using VB
Is there a central place where where I could have switched it off? Cos this is spread all over the project!

Comment: David, ANY property/field is showing this problem!

Comment: Add the code for the IBS_DAL module, at least the module/namespace definition and the property definition.

Comment: Gusman, sample code added above.

Comment: vb project has namespaces import in properties... Well. Try to clean solution,  close it, remove .suo file and open it again.

Comment: Tried that T.S., but still errors remained.

Comment: In the properties of your project, what is the "Root Namespace" set to? And do you have any `Namespace` statements?  Where is `IBS_DAL` defined?  If it's in another project, is that project referenced?

Comment: Root Namespace is IBS_DAL. I'm not sure is there are any other Namespace statements in other Projects, but shouldn't. IBS_DAL is defined only in the IBS_DAL project. From other projects, I can easily reference the IBS_DAL properties. Only from within the IBS_DAL Project I cannot reference the properties using the Namespace. Without the Namespace or Using the Global in front, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Found the bug.

Found an *Auto Generated* code in file `IBS_DAL.Designer`.
Since it generated a class named `IBS_DAL`, this conflicted with the Namespace `IBS_DAL`.

Do not know how his code was generated. Just remarked the contents and excluded the file from the project.